# Elasticsearch [2.3] - suggest query not returning updated document

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I've been trying to update a few auto-suggest documents in elastic:

```
{"update":{"_index":"my_autosuggest_index", "_type":"my_autosuggest_type", "_id": "123"}}
{"doc" : {my-updated-doc}, "doc_as_upsert" : true}
```

The update works, when directly asking for the updated doc 123 using

```
GET /my_autosuggest_index/my_autosuggest_type/123
```

I do see the updated doc.

However, when querying for the updated doc using:

```
/my_autosuggest_index/_suggest

{
  "hotels-suggest": {
    "text": "London",
    "completion": {
      "field": "suggest",
      "size": 10,
      "context": {
        "displayType": "Airports"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get `doc 123` before the update.

Tried clearing the cache - still getting the non-updated doc.

I could not find any documentation or think of any other explanation for this weird behavior.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue. It occurs due to the way elasticsearch handles updates and deletes of documents.

You can read a bit about it [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up#index-segments)

All documents in elasticsearch are immutable. As the documents are immutable, when you update the document, the old document is marked for deletion and a new document is created. The old document will be truly deleted when the segments in elasticsearch index merge. Here lies the problem. Somehow in my case when we used the suggestion query we got both results.

To overcome this you can force merge the segments after an update. This is slow but works.

`POST /index_name/_optimize?max_num_segments=1`

I think the optimize api is deprecated.

If it does not work the you can also use [force merge](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/indices-forcemerge.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've tried force merging - crushed the node due to not enough disk space..

Comment: oh!!..were you able to recover the data? and can you check the logs and see y it crashed? was there any other reasons apart from enough disk space.